# Нужны ли запятая и кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, заголовок

Как правильно написать заголовок к статье:

*Что такое солнечный лишай и как его лечить*

Нужны ли запятая и кавычки?

Answer (score 1):

Что такое солнечный лишай и как его лечить

Я думаю, что заголовок нужно оставить в таком виде.

Обычно заголовок не заключается в кавычки.

Знак вопроса не ставится, если статья — это ответ по этой теме.

Запятая не ставится, так как предложения связаны между собой общим элементом, хотя реально он отсутствует. Заголовок можно рассматривать как придаточную часть в предложении: Ответ на вопрос о том, что такое солнечный лишай и как его лечить.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если Вы имеете в виду **весь** заголовок, то его в кавычки не берут(если только это не полная цитата или ее часть):
   *"Пусть бегут неуклюже пешеходы по лужам..."*
   *Полиграф Шариков: "В очередь, сукины дети!"*

Заголовок — штука особенная, нужно сказать всё и — коротко.
"Как корабль назовешь, так он и поплывет" — как статью назовёшь, так её и прочитают.

Об особенностях заголовков можно посмотреть здесь: [**Виды и функции заголовков**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text28/0045.htm).
Об особенностях пунктуации — здесь: [**Знаки препинания в газетных и журнальных заголовках**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=168#pp168).

2. Если Вы имеете в виду *солнечный лишай*, то его тоже в кавычки не берут, т.к. это заболевание в медицине описано, а название зафиксировано:

cолнечный лишай (солнечный грибок, пляжная болезнь, разноцветный лишай) — лишай отрубевидный (*Pityriasis versicolor, tinea versicolor*).

3. Предложение имеет вопросительную интонацию, поэтому сюда подходит правило: запятая перед одиночным союзом "и" не ставится, если в состав сложносочинённого предложения входят вопросительные предложения.
   ([**Знаки препинания в сложносочинённых предложениях**](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/733-12_znaki_prepinaniya_v_slozhnosochinennyh_predlozheniya))

Ставить ли знак вопроса в конце заголовка? — это уже дело автора:

Что такое гонартроз и как его лечить?
Что такое тяжелая лихорадка денге и как ее лечить?
Чем мне грозит флюороз и как его лечить?
Что делать при флюсе и чем его лечить
Что такое солнечный лишай и как его лечить